Unable to ge SubGroup Id in KeyCloak using Admin REST API
I'm working with Key Cloak Admin REST API to get the SubGroup ID in scala.
Firstly I've generated Access Token.
Then I've created group using that Access Token in authorization, group created successfully and able to access the group ID.
After that I've created subgroup using above Access Token and parentGroupID, the subgroup is also created which I've confirmed on the UI.
The problem occurred when I try to get the SubGroup ID, it is giving empty([]).
Method to create SubGroup:
def createSubGroup(keycloakHost: String, realm: String, accessToken: String, childGroup: Group, parentGroupName: String): Future[Unit] = {

      val parentGroupIdFuture = getGroupId(keycloakHost, realm, accessToken, parentGroupName)
      parentGroupIdFuture.flatMap { parentGroupId =>

        val createSubGroupUrl = s"$keycloakHost/admin/realms/$realm/groups/$parentGroupId/children"

        val request = HttpRequest(
          method = HttpMethods.POST,
          uri = createSubGroupUrl,
          headers = List(Authorization(OAuth2BearerToken(accessToken))),
          entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, childGroup.toJson.toString())
        )

        Http().singleRequest(request).flatMap { response =>
          if (response.status == StatusCodes.Created) {
            Future.successful(())
          } else {
            Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String].flatMap { entity =>
              Future.failed(new Exception(s"Failed to create Sub Group, status code: ${response.status}, entity: $entity"))
            }
          }
        }
      }.recoverWith {
        case ex =>
          Future.failed(new Exception(s"HTTP request failed: ${ex.getMessage}"))
      }
    }

Method to get Group ID:
def getSubGroupId(keycloakHost: String, realm: String, accessToken: String, parentGroupName: String, subGroupName: String): Future[Option[String]] = {

      val parentGroupIdFuture = getGroupId(keycloakHost, realm, accessToken, parentGroupName)

      parentGroupIdFuture.flatMap { parentGroupId =>
        println("parentGroupId", parentGroupId)
        val getParentGroupUrl = s"$keycloakHost/admin/realms/$realm/groups/$parentGroupId"

        val request = HttpRequest(
          method = HttpMethods.GET,
          uri = getParentGroupUrl,
          headers = List(Authorization(OAuth2BearerToken(accessToken)))
        )

        Http().singleRequest(request).flatMap { response =>
          response.status match {
            case StatusCodes.OK =>
              Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String].flatMap { responseStr =>
                println("Raw JSON Response:", responseStr)
                val jsonObj = responseStr.parseJson.asJsObject
                println("jsonObj", jsonObj)

                // Check if the "subGroups" field is populated
                val subGroupsArray = jsonObj.fields.get("subGroups") match {
                  case Some(JsArray(elements)) if elements.nonEmpty =>
                    elements.map(_.asJsObject)
                  case _ =>
                    Seq.empty[JsObject]
                }

                println("subGroupsArray", subGroupsArray)

                // Search for the desired subgroup by name
                val subGroupIdOpt = subGroupsArray.find { subGroupJson =>
                  subGroupJson.fields.get("name").contains(JsString(subGroupName))
                }.flatMap { subGroupJson =>
                  subGroupJson.fields.get("id").map(_.convertTo[String])
                }

                subGroupIdOpt match {
                  case Some(subGroupId) =>
                    println(s"Subgroup '$subGroupName' found with ID: $subGroupId")
                    Future.successful(Some(subGroupId))
                  case None =>
                    println(s"Subgroup '$subGroupName' not found")
                    Future.successful(None)
                }
              }

            case _ =>
              Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String].flatMap { entity =>
                Future.failed(new Exception(s"Failed to retrieve parent group details, status code: ${response.status}, entity: $entity"))
              }
          }
        }.recoverWith {
          case ex => Future.failed(new Exception(s"HTTP request failed: ${ex.getMessage}"))
        }
      }
    }

The output is:
(Raw JSON Response:,{"id":"e0b646be-b813-44a4-b224-86f8d943ff74","name":"abc-group","path":"/abc-group","subGroupCount":1,"subGroups":[],"attributes":{"LASTNAME":["Technologies"],"FIRSTNAME":["abc"]},"realmRoles":["abc-role"],"clientRoles":{"abc-client":["abc-role"]},"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}})
    
    Subgroup 'abc-sub-group' not found

Although the subGroupCount is 1 but subGroups is [].
Guide me where I'm doing wrong while getting SubGroupId.
